# How do I determine the equation of a Sinusoidal Function given points on the line?

Tags: trigonometry

Specifically, I am struggling to do this in scenarios where I have an incomplete cycle, and a maximum, but no specific minimum. Here is an example question from a practice sheet I received:

At Canada's Wonderland, a thrill seeker can ride the Xtreme Skyflyer. This is essentially a large pendulum of which the rider is the bob. A vertical net for safety is included. The rider's horizontal distance to the safety net is given for various times:

| Time(s) | Distance from net (m) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 55 |
| 1 | 53 |
| 2 | 46 |
| 3 | 36 |
| 4 | 25 |
| 5 | 14 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 8 | 8 |
| 9 | 15 |

Create a graph of the distance of the pendulum from the net with respect to time, then find the graph's amplitude, period, vertical translation, and phase shift for this function.

I have created a graph, seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYQkh.jpg), and I believe that I need to use a cosine function for this, but I am struggling to find the specific transformations that I should apply to said function, given that I do not know the minimum. How can I do this?

Comment: They aren't really specifying much in terms of significant figures, so you're probably fine assuming the minimum is 5m.